# Remove Translation from Matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, translation

Is it possible to remove just the translation element from a Matrix object so that only Scale and Rotation elements remain?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just zero out the appropriate matrix elements. In a 4x4 3D-transform matrix, these are stored as the three first elements in either in the rightmost column or bottom row, depending on whether you use pre- or post-multiplication.

If your Matrix class has a method to get the translation, it probably also has a method to add translations. In that case, just add the opposite translation of what you already have.